# Scroll effect isn't working correctly

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua, roblox

I've been making a minigame game in ROBLOX for a while and one of the things in my game is a scrolling effect for when it's choosing a game. You can see what I'm talking about [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HVfQ.jpg). Also in this gif, you can see my problem. The effect scrolls from bottom to top. It should go from top to bottom.

I can't really see why it does this so I'm not really sure what to do.

Here's the code responsible for the effect:

```
for i, v in pairs(P:GetChildren()) do
    local ll
    local lastpicked        
    local t = P:GetChildren()
    local menuItems = #t -- number of menu items
    local repeats = 1 -- Repeated
    for R = math.random(65,95) + math.random(menuItems), 1, -1 do
        ll = t[repeats].SurfaceGui.TextLabel
        local lastbcolor = ll.BackgroundColor3
        ll.BackgroundColor3 = BrickColor.Yellow().Color
        wait( R^-.7*.7 ) -- 
        ll.BackgroundColor3 = lastbcolor
        repeats = repeats % menuItems + 1
    end
    ll = t[repeats].SurfaceGui.TextLabel
    for R = 1, 5 do
        local lastbcolor = ll.BackgroundColor3
        ll.BackgroundColor3 = BrickColor.new("Bright green").Color
        wait( .3 )
        ll.BackgroundColor3 = lastbcolor
        lastpicked = ll
        map = maps:FindFirstChild(ll.Text):Clone()
        wait( .3 )
    end
    break
end
```

Comment: you cycle through your list from element 1 to #t so your menu items are most likely just ordered that way. this cannot be answered without seeing your menu implementation.

Comment: The menu is ordered the right way. I've already made sure of that. The top menu item is at the top of the list and at the top in the explorer hierarchy as-well as the rest of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
for R = math.random(65,95) + math.random(menuItems), 1, -1 do
```

Is making you go through them backwards. Given the code

```
for R = a, b, c do
```

`a` is the starting value of `R`, `b` is the finishing value of `R`, and `c` is the increment. The way you have it right now is making it go from the last value to the first value. Try changing it to

```
for 1, R = math.random(65,95) + math.random(menuItems), 1 do
```

Did this work?

Note: you can simplify that line of code by omitting the `, 1` at the end:

```
for 1, R = math.random(65,95) + math.random(menuItems) do
```

You can do this because if you omit the `c`, then it has an implied value of 1.